# Client Application Services call ASP.net MVC5?

Tags: c#, asp.net, owin, asp.net-mvc-5

I am revising an existing desktop C# program to enable user login with the same login credentials of any existing (and pretty standard) ASP.net MVC5 website. Essentially, the C# program will prompt the user for user name and password, then will contact the MCV 5 website for authentication. Note the desktop application and the website (or IIS servers) are not in same domain.

Not familiar with this part, so I did some search, and noticed the "Client Application Services" as mentioned in this page: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb546195(v=vs.110).aspx

My question is: the above page is for Visual studio 2010. -- Does newer version of VS still support that? Or there is better way to achieve the same/similar goal?

Any trade offs or pit-falls in the said scenario? (or any security risk of doing that? Like, how does it encrypt the user name and password in the transmission, etc.)